# Send Ctrl+Shift+(minus) in Python

Tags: python, python-keyboard

I have a hopefully quick one for the experts here.

I'm writing a script in python that will eliminate repetitive typing into a GL.
It's mostly working, but I'm at a roadblock.
Using the keyboard package, I'm trying to send ctrl+shift+(minus). I can't seem to get this to work. Even when I just try to send "-" or "minus" or "hyphen" using `keyboard.write()` it doesn't respond properly.

I'm not opposed to using a different package if needed.

Comment: What is "a GL"?

Comment: pyautogui may be able to help

Comment: Do you mean [this `keyboard` library](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)?

Comment: Yep. That is the library I'm using Chris. GL is General Ledger. I have to enter up to 150 lines in a single sheet from another spreadsheet. I had been hoping to import it to the program, but I don't see support for it. So instead I'm trying to automate my keystrokes.

SuperStew, I didn't see anything with pyautogui that will allow me to send a minus key. I'll google more.

Answer (score 0):

SuperStew was right.
pyautogui is the way to go.
In case anyone else has a similar issue, you'll need to import pyautogui and to get ctrl+shift+minus it's

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.keyDown('-')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
pyautogui.keyUp('-')
```

Thanks so much for all of your help!